# Steps in evaluating infinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

This is my teacher's work. "

[image]

"

How does the the $a^2\ln(a)/2)$  lose the $1/2$ part when its limit is taken?
I.E. the step following $a^2\ln(a)/2$ is limit as a approaches 0 from the right side of $a\ln(a)$. Where did the $1/2$ go?

The derivative of $\ln(u)$ is $du/dx(1/x)$. takin the derivative of $\ln(a)$, where $a$ is a constant, should yield zero. but that is not so in the last steps of taking the limit as $x$ approaches 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fractional $\frac{1}{2}$ isn't really "lost", it just looks like your teacher "stepped out" of the integral temporarily to evaluate the limit $\lim_{a \to 0^+} a^2\ln(a)$. Once your teacher established that $$\lim_{a \to 0^+} a^2\ln(a) = 0$$ you simply use the fact that $$\lim_{a \to 0^+} \left(c \cdot a^2\ln(a) \right) =c \cdot \left( \lim_{a \to 0^+} a^2\ln(a)\right) \\ = c \cdot 0 \\ = 0$$ for any constant number $c$. In your case, $c = \frac{1}{2}$, but again it doesn't matter what coefficient is attached to the limit.

Comment: I wouldn't call it redundant, as your teacher firmly establishes that $$\lim_{a \to 0^+}\frac{a^2\ln(a)}{2} = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{a^3}{-2a} \\ = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{-a^2}{2}$$ You need this work so there is no question about the validity of plugging in $a = 0$